# Spring JPA inserting to wrong column when saving multiple entities

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have encountered an issue where I save a list of entities all at once, sometimes some rows have values being written to wrong columns.

Basically, I have a **Movie** entity, which extends **Show** (annotated with `@MappedSuperclass`), which extends **TraceableEntity** that is also annotated with `@MappedSuperclass` as shown below:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(TraceableEntity.TraceableEntityListener.class)
public abstract class TraceableEntity {
    @Column
    private Date createdOn;

    @Column
    private Date dateUpdated;

    public Date getCreatedOn() {
        return createdOn;
    }

    public void setCreatedOn(Date createdOn) {
        this.createdOn = createdOn;
    }

    public Date getDateUpdated() {
        return dateUpdated;
    }

    public void setDateUpdated(Date dateUpdated) {
        this.dateUpdated = dateUpdated;
    }

    public static class TraceableEntityListener {
        @PrePersist
        public void beforeInsert(TraceableEntity entity) {
            if (entity.getCreatedOn() == null) {
                entity.setCreatedOn(new Date());
            }
        }

        @PreUpdate
        public void beforeUpdate(TraceableEntity entity) {
            entity.setDateUpdated(new Date());
        }
    }
}
```

Now, on some occasions, the value of **createdOn** ends up in **dateUpdated**, as shown in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iV94w.png).

In a nutshell, my application is a scraper that retrieves data from an API. I'm using `RestTemplate` in `CompletableFuture` to download data concurrently, and then save everything in one go. The method in which `.save(...)` is invoked is annotated with `@Transactional`. When the size of the list is under approximately 1500 the saving is fine, it seems that things go wrong when the size exceeds 1500 for some reason. I'd really appreciate your time and help in this matter!

Comment: the strange thing is that if I scrape only the rows that have `createdOn` in `dateUpdated` (i.e. the last 4 entries in the screenshot), everything is fine... I have no clue what's going on here...

Comment: suppose if you want a auditing mechanism with Spring I think going with  Spring data auditing is easy. refer this [example](http://www.baeldung.com/database-auditing-jpa)

Answer (score 0):

Does it always happen at the same place?  Are you missing some rows for example? perhaps the text of some of the stuff you're scraping has special characters that were not escaped properly?  You may want to turn on your logging to see exactly what is being sent to the server.

The reason that if you scrape just the "problematic" movies and it turns out fine is probably because the actual problem occurred before the movies in question.

Comment: Hi Jeff, I just figured out that it's an issue with the API not my code...